# AV1 extract keyframes

Tags: ffmpeg, video, mp4, codec

Using this file [1], I can run this command with no problem:

```
ffmpeg -i crushed-between-two-portals.mp4 %d.jpg
```

but if I run either of these commands [2]:

```
ffmpeg -i crushed-between-two-portals.mp4 -vf "select='eq(pict_type,I)'" %d.jpg
ffmpeg -i crushed-between-two-portals.mp4 -vf "select='eq(pict_type,PICT_TYPE_I)'" %d.jpg
```

I get this result:

```
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters
if used)
```

I think it is because of the video stream:

```
Stream #0:0(und): Video: av1 (Main) (av01 / 0x31307661), yuv420p(tv, bt709),
1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 19 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 60k tbn, 60k tbc
(default)
```

I have used this command before with other codecs. How can I extract keyframes
or similar from AV1 codec?

1. https://f002.backblazeb2.com/file/ql8mlh/crushed-between-two-portals.mp4
2. [Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](//trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg offers two decoders for AV1, `dav1d` and `libaom`. The issue in question
was due to an error in the `libaom` decoder [1].

This has now been fixed [2], and new release available [3].

1. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/9180
2. https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/8b954a72
3. https://github.com/GyanD/codexffmpeg/releases/tag/2021-04-18-git-d43b26b30d